# optimizing Array results with multiple if values

Tags: java, android, arrays, position

I want to have (yourItems.contains("Gin")) [show all drinks for gin] + (yourItems.contains("Vodka")) [show all drinks for vodka] THEN move the drinks that contain both to the top of the list.

Right now my application crashes as soon as I select both values Gin and Vodka

```
private List<Drinks> myDrinks = new ArrayList<Drinks>(); 
private ArrayList<String> yourItems;
```

...

```
    private void populateDrinkList() {

    if (yourItems.contains("Gin")){
     myDrinks.add(new Drinks("a"));
     myDrinks.add(new Drinks("b"));
     myDrinks.add(new Drinks("c"));
     myDrinks.add(new Drinks("d"));
     myDrinks.add(new Drinks("e"));

     if (yourItems.contains("Vodka")) {

           Drinks toMoveUp = new Drinks("e");
            while (myDrinks.indexOf(toMoveUp) != 0) {
            int i = myDrinks.indexOf(toMoveUp);
            Collections.swap(myDrinks, i, i-1 );
    }
     }

    }
    populateListView();
}
```

This is the Drinks class

```
public class Drinks {
String name = null;



    public Drinks(String name){
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
}
    }
```

Log cat: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WatONhY7mSsR6Wjs6haZnfNWPSeY0dpusvlbDxnHN5M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ok buddy tell me what kind of error is your program giving you when crashing ?

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException (is that what you are looking for?) sorry I'm brand new to java and applications I only used Unity C# for a little bit.

Comment: added log cat to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have understood what is the problem of your code

inside the `Drinks` class add this to your code:

```
    @Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Drinks other = (Drinks) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

in the other one leave it like that:

```
private void populateDrinkList() {

     myDrinks.add(new Drinks("a"));
     myDrinks.add(new Drinks("b"));
     myDrinks.add(new Drinks("c"));
     myDrinks.add(new Drinks("d"));
     myDrinks.add(new Drinks("e"));

     if (yourItems.contains("Vodka") || yourItems.contains("Gin") ) {

           Drinks toMoveUp = new Drinks("e");
            while (myDrinks.indexOf(toMoveUp) != 0) {
            int i = myDrinks.indexOf(toMoveUp);
            Collections.swap(myDrinks, i, i-1 );
    }


    }
    populateListView();
}
```

Comment: Still crashes when i run it, now with only selecting one of the values

Comment: what is the exception that is giving you now ?

Comment: Fatal exception :main . Caused by IndexOutOfBoundsException at swap(collections.java)

Answer (score 0):

```
Drinks toMoveUp = new Drinks("e");
 while (myDrinks.indexOf(toMoveUp) != 0)
```

In the above code what you are doing is that you are creating a new object of Drinks, and looking for its index in myDrinks array list.This will always return -1 as this new Drinks object(toMoveUp) is not there in your myDrinks array list.
so,  **Collections.swap(myDrinks, i, i-1 ) will be  Collections.swap(myDrinks, -1, -2)**;
This will cause an index out of bound exception.
A solution for this will be to add an identifier in Drinks class it identify wheather it is a,b,c,d or e.
Then iterate thru myDrinks to find index of the Drinks object which matches with your toMoveUp object using the identifier we created.Then swap using this index.
Hope this help you.

sample code-
//method to find index

```
private int getIndex(Drinks drinks){
int i = 0;
for(Drinks obj : myDrinks){
if(obj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(drinks.getName())){
return i;
}
i++;
}
return -1;
}
```

//modify your code as

```
    if (yourItems.contains("Vodka")) {

               Drinks toMoveUp = new Drinks("e");
int index = getIndex(toMoveUp);
                if(index != 0 && index !=-1) {

                Collections.swap(myDrinks, 0, index );
        }
         }
```

Comment: can you post code of your Drinks class, just the class member list will do

Comment: I added the Drinks class, I hope its what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

change your model to :

```
Map<String,List<Drink>>
```

that will hold the items for each item.
and then you will be able to do so :

```
if (yourItems.contains("Gin")){

    myDrinks.addAll(0,map.get("Gin"));
}
```

using addAll with 0 in the first parameter will move your added items to the top, this will save you the swapping part.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a multimap and a better Drink class.

1. Multimap

   ```
   private List<Drink> myDrinks = new ArrayList<Drink>();  
   // ...  
   HashMap<String, ArrayList<Drink>> allDrinks = getAllDrinks();  
   List<Drink> drinks = map.get(Drink.Type.Vodka);  
   myDrinks.addAll(0, drinks);  
   drinks = map.get(Drink.Type.Gin);  
   myDrinks.addAll(0, drinks);
   ```
2. Drink class
   Add an `inner enum` that will hold the `Drink` type. Add a property of type `Drink.Type` to save the drink's type. Override equals and add a comparator for drink

If you want to change the order of your items, sort them via the Drink's comparator or use an anonymous comparator when you're sorting it.

There are o couple of advantages for this solution, to name a few, you have a faster retrieval, no more `add(new(Drink(""))` and you have a clean way of ordering your items.

**Note:**
I am guessing that `myDrinks` list doesn't have zillions of Drinks so sorting it will not produce any performance issues.